# QT form buttons don't work on a QT form while a label is updated with a while loop

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have GUI application created in QT. It has some buttons and a label. 
The program gets images from a video file sequentially in a while loop and show them on a label by refreshing it. At start up, the buttons work properly but when I click play button and start video display, the other buttons cant be clicked, and if I insist of clicking them, program doesn't respond and stops working. I couldn't figure it out even though I've thought a lot on it. I don't think code is needed to show for this problem but if you request, I can post the related part of it

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Repaint method, instead of using repaint method you can just use

```
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
```

It must solve your problem.

Comment: Bulls Eye! That is what I just figured out. It solved the problem. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when your `while()` loop is executing, you are never returning control to the event loop. The event loop dispatches the queued repaint events etc. You will probably want to do it one image at a time in a slot triggered by a timer, like so:

```
class Gui {
Q_OBJECT
...
protected slots:
  void openFile(const QString &);
  void nextImage();
protected:
  QTimer imageTimer;
};

void Gui::Gui(...)
{
   ...
   connect(imageTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(nextImage());
   ...
}

void Gui::openFile(const QString & fileName)
{
   const int imagePeriod = 1000/25; // [ms], set to 25 frames per second
   ...
   imageTimer.start(imagePeriod);
}

void Gui::nextImage()
{
   QImage p;
   // read image from the file onto the image
   ui.label->setPixmap(p);
   // no need to call update() on the label!
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand my mistake thanks to you. repaint method doesn't work there. I used processEvent method instead and it works now. Thanks again.

Comment: Do not use `processEvents()` because it can reenter your code, and is just the wrong way to go about it. Yes, it works, but it's bad design. You want to update your image at a fixed rate: use a timer to trigger the update. You can be preparing QImages and stuffing them in a queue in a separate thread, and consume them in the Gui thread. Look at my other answers for insights into how interhtread communication works in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you show the images on a label?

It is likely you need a thread to read and loop the video. That way other inputs can still be processed and it won't crash your application.

Comment: Why not? A label in qt can show a picture by setPixmap method. It is not the main problem. It doesn't have to disable the buttons,. I probably overlook something. Because in my past projects, it was working with no problem. but when I use a loop, the form looks it stucks in loop and doesnt respond to my button clicks. For now, I'm not able to code with threads unfortunately.

Comment: "but when I use a loop, the form looks it stucks in loop ". I think that's the problem. I think you need a thread. They aren't too complicated. I recommend familiarizing yourself with them. :)

Comment: Thanks, I know I have to learn using threads :) But now I have to look for something else that I can.

Comment: It's not all that great of a suggestion to throw threads at someone who has trouble getting to terms with event loop in just one thread. Threads are not a panacea.